# How can I show poll options and hide vote button for anonymous users in advanced poll module?

Tags: polls

I am using [Advanced poll](https://www.drupal.org/project/advpoll) module to create polls in Drupal 7.

I want to show poll options and vote button to authenticated users, but I want to show poll options and a message instead of vote button to anonymous users.

I've achieved this by editing the advanced poll module, however I am scared of losing changes on core update.

Is there any hook or method to achieve this without editing core files?

Comment: Instead of modifying the module file, have you tried module permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have tried changing permissions too. If I set the poll to be open for authenticate users only, then anonymous users can't be able to see the poll options. If I set the poll to be open for everyone, anonymous users can be able to see the vote button too. I want to show the poll options but not the vote button to anonymous users.

Comment: OK. Create custom module and override your changes into it. Never modify any contributed or core module.

Comment: Thanks @NikhilBanait I have solved the issue using `hook_node_view` in my custom module. :)